# Networkx get multiple depths

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have a csv file that include multiple Directed Acrylic Graphs. I am trying to use the networkx to get the depth of each graph. but I don't know if it's the problem that I import all the graph as one. How can I import multiple DAG and calculate the longest path for each connected graph?

my csv file has two columns: source node and target node.
The format is like this;
source      target
1`source target`

```
source     target
 1           2
 1           3
 1           4
 4           5
 8           9
 9          10
```

this has two DAGs: one is 1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, and 4 to 5. And the second graph is 8 to 9 to 10. and I want to calculate the most longest depth for each graph and most longest width in each of the graphs.

my code can only generate one result that has longest depth among all the graphs. but I want it to show all the separate graphs with its longest depth.

My code is like below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("importfile.csv")
g= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='source', target = ‘target’, creat_using = nx.DiGraph())
longes_depth = nx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path_length(g)
print(longest_depth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the connected components in `g` first, and then iterate over the components, induce a subgraph on its constituent nodes, and compute your path lengths for each subgraph.

```
longest_depths = []
for component in nx.connected_components(g):
    subgraph = nx.subgraph(g, component)
    longest_depths.append(nx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path_length(subgraph))
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, i think the idea is make sense to me but I tried it gave me an error. The problem is that the algorithm connected_components() can be only applied to undirected graph and mine is directed graph and it shows that " not implemented for directed type". I am still trying. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably, you do not care about the directedness when defining the components. So you can simply call `nx.connected_components(g.to_undirected())` instead of `nx.connected_components(g)` in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure, and: any time.